# Fastlane: cannot use p12 file generated by "match" command

Tags: ios, encryption, match, twitter-fabric, fastlane

I am configuring Fastlane and their `match` command to generate my Certificates and provisionings. All files are stored in a private github repo as recommended in the fastlane docs.

All worked properly, certificates and provisionings were generated and stored in my private repo, including the p12 file for the certificates.
But when I try to download this p12 file (to run my app in Xcode) it seems to be encripted.

The `match` command encripted the p12 before uploading it to github, so the question is:

--> How can I download and decrypt the p12 file generated by `match` command in my private repo??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I didn't needed to decrypt the p12 files by myself. I just needed to configure a special provisioning profile from Fastlane in my build settings.

Project --> Build Settings --> Code Signing --> Provisioning Profile: `$(sigh_<bundle_identifier>_<profile_type>)`

`<bundle_identifier>` : App Bundle ID

`<profile_type>`: `appstore` for distribution, and `development` for development

Answer (score 4):

If you want to manually decrypt a file (https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/#manual-decrypt)

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -k "<password>" -in "<fileYouWantToDecryptPath>" -out "<decryptedFilePath>" -a -d
```